# Material UI Autocomplete: Sync value with state

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How to store values from [Material-UI's Autocomplete](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/) into React's state. Autocomplete uses multiselect and has Array of strings as value.

Comment: Ciao, @Amel, put the answer on question, otherwise seems that you have already answered to your question :)

Comment: Hi Giovanni Esposito,
actually I have answered my own question. In stackoverflow I found many similar questions, but none was really a solution to my problem. After solving it by myself I wanted to share my results with the world. Somewhere in Stackoverflow I have read that you can directly answer your own question to share knowledge and that encouraged me to do it. After 2 days I can choose my answer as the accepted one.

Comment: Oh ok, I thought was a mistake because answer appeared after 1 minute. But ok, in this case it's ok like you did. Sorry for misunderstanding (and thanks to sharing :) )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Example with a functional component**

In this example we will show an Autocomplete Component with multiple select and checkboxes for each option.

Define state with initial value (In our case: Empty Array):

```
  const [ndl, setNdl] = React.useState([]);
```

Options which we can select:

```
const ndlExample = ['Berlin', 'München', 'Saarbrücken', 'Köln'];
```

Autocomplete Component:

```
           <Autocomplete
              multiple
              value={ndl}
              id="areaFilterId"
              options={ndlExample}
              limitTags={1}
              disableCloseOnSelect
              getOptionLabel={option => option}
              onChange={(event: any, value: string[] | null) => setNdl(value)}
              renderOption={(option, { selected }) => (
                <React.Fragment>
                  <Checkbox icon={icon} checkedIcon={checkedIcon} style={{ marginRight: 8 }} checked={selected} />
                  {option}
                </React.Fragment>
              )}
              style={{ width: 280 }}
              renderInput={params => <TextField {...params} variant="standard" label="Niederlassung" />}
            />
```

[Material's UI Autocomplete API](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/)

Comment: Could you please share the onChange syntax when not using TypeScript? Thanks!

Comment: @JayJ if you just remove the types it should be like `onChange={(event, value) => setNdl(value)}`

Comment: Tnx this help me to see that my selected array is not same type as value so i crate new class with two params , one is slectedObjects: Array<Object> and other is filterIdsArray which is type Array<string>. Then on setState i put selectedObjects : values and then it work

Comment: Thank you so much. This saves my day.